# PHPExcel Iterate through sheets getting specific cells in each

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to iterate through Excel worksheets to obtain specific cells on each sheet.

It iterates through the worksheets just fine, printing the index.  But the reference to the active sheet doesn't change.  I get the same information from the first worksheet with each iteration.

Here is what I have ...

```
<?php

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <style>
                table th {
                    text-align: right;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }

                table td {
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,3, 0.1);
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>";

/** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = '01hospital.xlsx';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}


foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet number - ', $objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet) , PHP_EOL;

    $division = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C3');
    $hospital = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B5');
    $site_id = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C6');
    $address = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C7');
    $phone = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C8');
    $time_zone = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C9');
    $mhbs = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F12'); // Default 0
    $mh_inc = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F13'); // Default $0
    $ms_inc = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F14'); // Default $0
    $mnwdo = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I15');
    $facility_rate = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D16');
    $mndo = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H17'); // Default 10
    $mnpo = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H18'); // Default 2
    $dosd = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J21'); // Default 60
    $reseot = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J22'); // Default 15
    $odnas = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J23'); // Default 'No'
    $ssnas = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J24'); // Default 'No'



    echo "<table>
            <tr><th>Division:</th><td>$division</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Hospital</th><td>$hospital</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Site ID</th><td>$site_id</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Address</th><td>$address</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Phone</th><td>$phone</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Time Zone</th><td>$time_zone</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Minimum Hours Between Shifts</th><td>$mhbs</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Max Hourly INC</th><td>$mh_inc</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Max Shift INC</th><td>$ms_inc</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Max Number of Weekend Days Off</th><td>$mnwdo</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Facility Rate</th><td>\$$facility_rate</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Max Number of Days Off</th><td>$mndo</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Max Number of Providers Off per Day</th><td>$mnpo</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Day Off Submission Deadline</th><td>$dosd</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Reminder Email Sent to Enter Off Time</th><td>$reseot</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Do Off Days Need Approval by Scheduler?</th><td>$odnas</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Does Swapping Shifts Need Approval by Scheduler?</th><td>$ssnas</td></tr>
        </table>
        <hr />";
}

    echo "Success: ".date('H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the active sheet doesn't change when you iterate through the worksheets. It doesn't need to change, and indeed it shouldn't change.... but you shouldn't need to care either.

The whole point is that you're assigning the current worksheet in the iteration to `$worksheet` so you access cells using that.

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheetNbr => $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet number - ', $worksheetNbr, PHP_EOL;

    $division = $worksheet->getCell('C3');
    ....
}
```

And (as shown above) you can also pick up the worksheet index via the foreach as well, without needing to call `$objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet)`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have included PHPExcel_IOFactory use static method 'load'

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePatch);
```

then get an array of sheets names

```
$sheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
```

then you have this:

```
foreach ($sheetNames as $sheetNameIndex => $sheetName)
    {
        $sheet =   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheetName)->toArray(null,true,true,true); //sets and returns active sheet

        //parse each array and insert them into database
    }
```

in $sheet variable you have exel sheet as an array

Answer (score 0):

Not five minutes after posting my question, I found the following work-around:

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet number - ', $objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet) , PHP_EOL;
    $index =  $objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet);

    $division = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($index)->getCell('C3');

    //  Rest of code here ...
}
```